# Does kapt support jdk 11?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kapt

I have a gradle project with kapt, when I build it I get:

```
> Task :backend:kaptKotlin
w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper' less than -source '11'
```

As I understand this's why I build it with jdk11, it's possible to force kapt use 11 instead of 8?

Comment: There are open tasks in JetBrains:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41431 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49947